# What is the fastest way to open a file in gvim

Tags: vim

Let's say if I want to open a file in a specific path

```
C:\Program files\vim\_vimrc
```

Then what is the best/fast way to open the file with minimal actions or typing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:e **/filename<tab>
:e **/*name<tab>
```

Note that this can be a bit slow when traversing large/deep directories.

With the right value for `path`, `wildignore` and `wildignorecase`, the `:find` command can be awesome:

```
:find *foo
```

There are also obviously many plugins if you want, like [CtrlP](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) or [VimFindsMe](https://github.com/dahu/VimFindsMe).

Comment: Great, that's exactly what i want. Basically I am looking for the traversing command so not necessary to install NERDTree. Now you are my best answer ! thanks !

Comment: Question: how to open the file in a split window?

Comment: You can also use <ctrl>-d to list the possible matches when using "e" with wildcards (may be less awkward than using <tab> if you are exploring)

Answer (score 1):

`:e c:\P` followed by tab until it hits `Program Files`, then `v` followed by tab until you hit `vim`, then `_v` followed by tabs until you hit `_vimrc`.